# Convert 3d Model to c++ Header file for Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

We are creating AR application on android. We have not much experience with AR. We have downloaded Vuforia SDK and sample project for Android. While tracking some images teapot is appeared on the screen. And its details(coordinates and so on) are included in teapot.h file. So we want to create our own 3d objects and convert them to such header files. How we can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's one script that can be used to convert .OBJ files into C/C++ arrays;  https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free 3d authoring application Blender (http://www.blender.org)

and the BlenderVuforiaExport exporter script available here:

https://github.com/StickyBeat/BlenderVuforiaExport

Answer (score 0):

you can export to a C++ header file from Blender.
You should try that.